# How to download a webpage source and show in webbrowser?

Tags: c#, proxy, browser, webbrowser-control, webclient

So I wanted to know if there is a way to download a webpage's source code and then show it in a webbrowser.

My main problem is user is going to use a web proxy in my application and sometimes these proxies have username and password but I don't want the user to always input his/her own password for the browser so I thought that I make a webclient request and set proxy and user/pass for it then download the source of the requested page and then show it in the webbrowser but if you know a way to for example give the webbrowser username and password please let me know.

thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what proxy would ask the user for username/password, it's usually configured in IE settings (in which case a browser won't ask) Are you sure it's the proxy asking for credentials and not the web site you're connecting to?

Comment: Authentication is baked into HTTP.. why wouldn't a proxy ask?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
WebClient.downloadString();
```

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx)

But I suggest that you display the source in a good Editor like Notepad++ instead of a WebBrowser.

Edit: I don't know about passing username and passwort for the proxy though.

Edit2: `webClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName",
"Password", "Domain");`